# Change Imageview image in tableview cell at selected index

Tags: ios, objective-c

If I select another `cell` image stays same for the previous `cell`, please help me out.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    VoteDeatailTableViewCell *cell = [_voteTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"VoteDeatailTableViewCell"];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.imgRadio.image  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_uncheck"];
    return cell;

}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    VoteDeatailTableViewCell *cell = [_voteTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.imgRadio.image  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_check"];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Show `deselectRowAtIndexPath` method

Comment: I haven't used 'deselectRowAtIndexPath' method

Comment: Then use it and change the cell image back

Comment: can you help me with code here

Comment: Please elaborate your question. You're changing the image on `didSelect` event, It will remain same until you reload the `table` or change it somewhere else.

Comment: If I select cell image is changing but if I select another cell image should be changed only for the newly selected index but the image stays same for the previously selected index also

Comment: Yes but for that you will have to change the last cell image as I said it will remain same until you reload the table or do it somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, how to change that image can you help me with a code?

Comment: You can use `didSelect` delegate. When you select another cell, `didSelect` method will be call for last selected cell and you can change its image here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your cell `imageView` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` so when you scroll your `tableView` it mismatched.

so my suggestion is that add selected `indexPath` in `NSMutableArray` and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` check that array contains selected `indexPath` if it contains than set `radio_check` image otherwise set `radio_uncheck` image like below. Define `NSMutableArray` globally.

```
NSMutableArray *arrSelectedImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    VoteDeatailTableViewCell *cell = [_voteTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"VoteDeatailTableViewCell"];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    if ([arrSelectedImages containsObject:indexPath]) {
        cell.imgRadio.image  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_check"];
    }
    else {
        cell.imgRadio.image  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_uncheck"];
    }

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [arrSelectedImages removeAllObjects];
    [arrSelectedImages addObject:indexPath];
    [self.tblVW reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Why not just reload the cell instead of whole table?

Comment: You will have to reload two cells ... The last selected and new one so that it can update the image of last cell too.

Comment: @SravanKumar  if you want to selected only 1 cell image as  `radio_check `.

Comment: @SravanKumar Okay.

Comment: @Kuldeep - if you used the single indexpath, in here no need of arrSelectedImages array concept, single indexpath assign is enough